# RestHeart ACL - User access controls for databases

Tags: acl, restheart

I'm using restheart 6, with mongoAclAuthorizer and mongoRealmAuthenticator.

I have no problem managing users or databases, but I'm not understanding how to restrict a user to access only the databases I allow.

I'm reading the documentation (https://restheart.org/docs/security/authorization/) about ACL, but I didn't find what I need.
By looking at the examples, looks like a user from the role "users" would be able to access all databases.

I guess the answer is in the predicate.
Let's say I have two users: ***userA*** and ***userB*** both with the role "user". I want ***userA*** to access ***database1*** and ***userB*** to access ***database2***.

The way the doc shows, looks like it's missing something that I wrote in brackets, which I know it doesn't exists, it is only to exemplify) ([user=userA] and [user=userB]).

```
role: user
predicate: [user=userA] and path-prefix[path="/database1"] and method[value="GET"] 
role: user
predicate: [user=userB] and path-prefix[path="/database2"] and method[value="GET"]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does anyone knows where is the "predicate" documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than it looks.
The roles "admin" and "user" are not mandatory.
You can create your own roles and use them as needed.

In my case above, I created four new roles: ***role-database1-rw***, ***role-database1-ro***, ***role-database2-rw*** and ***role-database2-ro***.

And I've attached the ***userA*** to the roles ***role-database1-rw*** and ***role-database2-ro***, and the ***userB*** to  to the roles ***role-database1-ro*** and ***role-database2-rw***.

Then, I created the ACLs:

```
roles: role-database1-rw
predicate: "path-prefix[/database1] and (method[GET] or method[POST] or method[PUT] or method[DELETE])"

roles: role-database1-ro
predicate": "path-prefix[/database1] and method[GET]"

roles: role-database2-rw
predicate: "path-prefix[/database2] and (method[GET] or method[POST] or method[PUT] or method[DELETE])"

roles: role-database2-ro
predicate: "path-prefix[/database2] and method[GET]"
```

This way, the userA can read from database1 and 2 and write on database1. And the userB can read from database1 and 2 and write on database2.

Comment: Let us know if we can improve the documentation, we are working to upgrade it for v6 and it's quite a load of work https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart-website